# How client port number of websocket get in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, webkit

In javascript create one websocket connect use new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws") and then use one  websocket connect established between server and client, but how client's  port number get in google chrome？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an application doesn’t select a particular port (i.e., in sockets terminology, it
doesn’t bind() its socket to a particular port), then TCP and UDP assign a unique ephemeral port (i.e., short-lived) number to the socket.
In this case, the application—typically a client—doesn’t care which port number it uses, but assigning a port is necessary so that the transport-layer protocols can identify the communication endpoints.
It also has the result that the peer application at the other end of the communication channel knows how to communicate with this application. TCP and UDP also assign an ephemeral port number if we bind a socket to port 0.
IANA specifies the ports in the range 49152 to 65535 as dynamic or private, with the intention that these ports can be used by local applications and assigned as ephemeral ports.
However, various implementations allocate ephemeral ports from different ranges.
On Linux, the range is defined by (and can be modified via) two numbers contained in the file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range.

In linux get port by below function：

```
Socket.c (linux-2.6.18/net/sctp): .get_port    = sctp_get_port,
Socket.c (linux-2.6.18/net/sctp): .get_port = sctp_get_port,
Tcp_ipv4.c (linux-2.6.18/net/ipv4): .get_port  = tcp_v4_get_port,
Tcp_ipv6.c (linux-2.6.18/net/ipv6): .get_port  = tcp_v6_get_port,
Udp.c (linux-2.6.18/net/ipv4): .get_port    = udp_v4_get_port,
Udp.c (linux-2.6.18/net/ipv6): .get_port    = udp_v6_get_port,
```

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket is an [`Upgrade`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism) of a HTTP connection which means it works over a TCP layer. The client is assigned any random port number by operating system to run and generally, we don’t care about it. That's why "high level" languages (like JavaScript in a browser context) don't even allow you to retrieve it at all.

Comment: Yes,I just want to know how it generated in google Chrome.....I want to know the code